# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException Spring MVC 4.2.5

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to get json response from my Spring Controller. Im getting below exception

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

I have jackson related jars in pom.xml as below

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my controller

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getNodes.htm",produces="application/json")
    public List<NodeDTO> getNodes() {
...
return nodes;
}
```

Im getting 406 error in the browser and above exception in server log. My browser is properly sending Accept header has application/json. But still Im facing this issue. I have gone through many forums none of them resolving my issue. Please help me to resolve it

Comment: I think you get error this  value = "/getNodes.htm"  what does mean "htm" pelase show your servlet-mapping in web xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@RequestMapping` annotation is incorrect, in particular the use of the extension `.htm`.

It should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getNodes.json",produces="application/json")
```

or perhaps

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getNodes",produces="application/json")
```

Spring MVC uses the extension of the URL to identify the type of content to return.  In your case, you're specifying an extension of `.htm`, which Spring interprets as HTML.  That however conflicts with the `produces` property of your annotation, which specifies JSON.

It's not clear to me exactly how Spring handles conflicting content types such as this, but if you replace the `.htm` extension with `.json` or drop the extension altogether, then you don't need to worry about it.